# I have an offset on my amchart chart (XY chart with cursor and zoom with 3 charts on one)

Tags: charts, amcharts

I have an offset on my Amchart chart.
It's an XY chart with cursor and zoom with 3 charts on one.
I search a lot on Amchart doc but I found nothing.

If you look at my capture, when i change the translate() value, i can edit the offset but i don't know how to setup my chart with the good method.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

[Capture of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYbIl.png)

Comment: question is not clear. can you explain more about what you need to do ?

Comment: It's quite explicit on the image, the three graphs are vertically offsetted so I want to rectify that